# Debugging org-babel snippets

Tags: org-babel

I'm using org-babel blocks to generate a Graphiz diagram for a presentation. Normally the output goes to a file which is what I want. However if the file is empty something went wrong. Is there an easy way to see stderr/stdout of the program, preferably separate from the file output?

Comment: Hmm, I see a temporary buffer `*Org-Babel Error Output*` raised in its own window when the command throws an error (dot, in this example).

Comment: @StuartHickinbottom: interesting, I do not. Maybe there is an option that controls it

Comment: Hacking around with the temp files org-babel drops it seems the dot tool returns 0 (i.e. success) even when the file has syntax errors.

Comment: I'm using GraphViz 2.38.0 on Fedora Linux, if that is relevant, and my dot definitely returns 1 in case of syntax error. That looks to be why I see the error output and you don't, though.

Comment: @StuartHickinbottom: I have 2.36 on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS so it looks like a version thing. I have since triggered core dumps in dotty with some excessive constraints and they did generate debug output.